# python .cpp read, append, save and close but dont works

Tags: python, c++, append

I'm a beginner and have the following task.

- a directory (folder) is to be searched for .cpp files (text) "done"
- in the files are opened and a certain string is searched + found "done"
- afterwards the found value is to be replaced by another (append) "also partly"
- and finally stored and closed "also works"

Problem is that my script finds the corresponding entry, it also changes "however everything which before and after comes" DELETES ""
What do I have to change?

Thanks.

```
import re    
with open("test.cpp", "r+") as f:
match = re.search("^(?P<Text1>.*)COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT\(\s*(?P<Text2>.+),(?P<Text3>\s*)(?P<Text4>\S*)(?P<Text5>\s*\)\s*;s*)",               "COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(TABLE_LENGTH(PopupType2ActionID) == EPopupType::ARRAY_SIZE , PopupType2ActionID_table_needs_revision);")

result = '"' + match.group('Text4') + '"'
```

if match:

```
print("%sPCC_STATIC_ASSERT(%s,%s%s" % (match.group('Text1'), 
match.group('Text2'), result, match.group('Text5')))

f.write("%sPCC_STATIC_ASSERT(%s,%s%s" % (match.group('Text1'), match.group('Text2'), result, match.group('Text5')))

f.close()
```

Comment: Where are you doing the match? re.search(string_to_search, line) --> in your case "line is hardcoded"? Could you please be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you are finding the string --> matched and afterward creating a new string.

Unfortunately the way you are doing is not proper (whatever programming language you are using). This is because your file is open as r+, but when you are writing the line all the rest is removed :-)

In order to do it properly you need to have a source file and a destination file otherwise you will only replace the whole file with one line:

```
f.write("%sPCC_STATIC_ASSERT(%s,%s%s" % (match.group('Text1'), match.group('Text2'), result, match.group('Text5')))
```

Ok Then what you can do is the follow, just to give it a try:
1) Move original file to a file~ (as Microsoft Word is doing):

```
import shutil
shutil.move( afile, afile+"~" )

destination= open( aFile, "w" )
source= open( aFile+"~", "r" )
```

2) Now you will only "READ" from the original and write to a NEW file that has the original name ;)

3) To make it easy you can now read line by line of the original file and:

```
for line in source:
    match = re.search(Your_matching, line)

    if <matching_condition>:
        destination.write( <New_LINE_after_match> + "\n" )
    else:
    # All the other lines without match, just write back same line
        destination.write(line)

source.close()
destination.close()
```

This will be already enough to generate a proper file. The ~ file you can then remove :-)

This is one way you can do it in python :-) Otherwise use the sed command on linux cli and modify the file :-)

Hope this clarify your query and solve your problem. Have a nice day!

Easy example below. In the txt file I have easy name:
     John
     Peter
     Marco
     Mickey
     Frank

```
import re,shutil,os
aFile = "marco.txt"
shutil.move( aFile, aFile+"~" )

destination= open(aFile, "w+" )
source= open(aFile+"~", "r" )

for line in source:
    match = re.search("Marco", line)

    if match:
        destination.write( "Modified_Line" + "\n" )
    else:
    # All the other lines without match, just write back same line
        destination.write(line)

source.close()
destination.close()

os.remove(aFile+"~")
```

Output for the marco.txt file will be after run the program:

```
 John
 Peter
 Modified_Line
 Mickey
 Frank
```

In your case this should solve the issue. Most probably the biggest problem will be the matching part for you. That you have to check better in detail in the re module, mine it is only an easy case. Please mark my answer if the question is solved.

Comment: i dont know what i must do?

Comment: Added some easy steps above :-) hope this help

Comment: ok. a little bit unstand it.

but i dont know how it insert it to my file

Comment: Can you be more precise? The idea above is to read line by line your original file and write back line by line. In case you match your "Special" line (can be also multiple match in a file) then you are appending the new line to the file and going ahead.

Comment: Added one complete example for you above. Have a nice day!

Comment: thx. but i would use the command:    f.read()  this means my instructor!
I do not know where i must insert it to my code?
finally this i have do!

Comment: with open("test.cpp", "w") as f:

       ##Do I have to paste it here and how?

    match = re.search("^(?P<Text1>.*)COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT\(\s*(?P<Text2>.+),(?P<Text3>\s*)(?P<Text4>\S*)(?P<Text5>\s*\)\s*;s*)","COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(TABLE_LENGTH(PopupType2ActionID) == EPopupType::ARRAY_SIZE , PopupType2ActionID_table_needs_revision);")
    result = '"' + match.group('Text4') + '"'
    if match:
           print("%sPCC_STATIC_ASSERT(%s,%s%s" % (match.group('Text1'), match.group('Text2'), result, match.group('Text5')))

Comment: If you want you can call source --> f and use f.readlines() to read. It is the same, that is only a name! the second sentence you wrote I did not get at all! The re.search() like that it is printing me an error. Please read about re module at python https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: import re

array = []

with open("test.cpp", "r") as f:
for line in f:
pattern = re.compile("^(?P<Text1>.*)COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT\(\s*(?P<Text2>.+),(?P<Text3>\s*)(?P<Text4>\S*)(?P<Text5>\s*\)\s*;s*)")
result = '"' + match.group('Text4') + '"'
if match:
array.append("%sPCC_STATIC_ASSERT(%s,%s%s" % (match.group('Text1'), match.group('Text2'), result, match.group('Text5')))
else:
array.append(line)




###datei öffnen (schreibend)
###zeile für zeile schreiben
###datei schliessen

Comment: Sorry but I cannot help. The code you sent is without sense....the pattern created with re.compile is not even used, then since the beginning you are using a group function that doesn't exist on a matching. I have only explained you what you are doing wrong and why the file is created only with the line you were writing. As said I hope you gain something and you should create a file as said to write everything correctly. Have a nice day.